# Run python script from java as subprocess

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to execute python code (live from the console, not just opening a single file).

```java
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("python");
Process process = builder.start();
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();
new Thread(() -> {
    String line;
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    // Ignore line, or do something with it
    while (true) try {
        if ((line = reader.readLine()) == null) break;
        else System.out.println(line);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();

final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
writer.println("1");
writer.println("2 * 2");
```

I tried this code, but after trying to push the following expressions `1` and `2*2`, I don't get a response (evaluation of my expressions).

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `python` code doesn't appear to print anything, and handling multiple threads to read and write to another process is a tricky topic; luckily, the functionality is built-in. You could do

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/env", "python",
        "-c", "print(2*2); exit()");
builder.inheritIO();
try {
    Process process = builder.start();
    process.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs

```
4
```

and terminates. For less trivial Python and Java integration, I would strongly suggest you look [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages#Java). As for your existing code, you never `exit()` python and you never `flush()` your `PrintWriter`. And you write on the `main` thread. And you need to pass `-i` to python, or it won't assume stdin is a console. Changing your code to

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/env", "python", "-i");
Process process = builder.start();

new Thread(() -> {
    String line;
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    // Ignore line, or do something with it
    while (true)
        try {
            if ((line = reader.readLine()) == null)
                break;
            else
                System.out.println(line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}).start();
new Thread(() -> {
    final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
    writer.println("1");
    writer.println("2 * 2");
    writer.println("exit()");
    writer.flush();
}).start();
```

Seems to work properly.

Comment: I was to have a long running python terminal, that I can at any point run commands on

Comment: If I wanted this solution, I could simply put the code in a python file, and execute that "python mycode.py"

Comment: Then I would suggest you use [Jython](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Jython) or one of the other integration packages (rolling your own REPL while trying to integrate with CPython is not my idea of fun).

Comment: I've checked out jython, but its a big dependency, and also doesn't make use of the system python version

Comment: @Tobiq Edited to work with your code. You need `-i` for `python`. Still would recommend another integration solution.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Question: what's wrong with writing on the main thread?

Comment: @Tobiq The destination *might **block***, the source you're reading from *could **block***. As I said, it's ***tricky***.

Comment: Do you know how I can output raw to the stdout, instead of printing? ---- Nevermind I've figured this out `sys.stdout.buffer.write`

Comment: And, do you know whether the evaluations of the expressions fed through the stdin are outputted to the stdout - if so, how to stop this?

Comment: Also, whats the purpose of `"/usr/bin/env"`

Comment: That's how you pick which [python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env) to run. Best of luck with your REPL!

Comment: I'm not even on Linux.

Comment: do you know whether it's possible to pass a file (python class to load) with the -i file. `python -i class.py` doesn't work